# Making div extend outside of container to fit full screen width (bootstrap)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a div inside a container that I wish to extend beyond the container to fit the screen width. I'm using bootstrap columns to create the divs.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="mydiv">
                Content
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The container has a set width however that only fills about 1200px and mydiv can't extend beyond that.

Comment: Please post your CSS too, especially .mydiv class.

Comment: Can you use `container-fluid`?

Comment: We need to see CSS in order to tell what other restrictions we're working with!

Comment: Turns out a div before that was being terminated prematurely. After fixing this the issue was resolved.

Comment: This question needs re-opening as it's about Bootstrap and the cited duplicate isn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can make the inner div have a position:absolute unless its parent has a position:relative.

Or you could use negative margins on your inner div.